# TYPO3: what is the field "access_group" for?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I don't know what is the field "access_group int(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL" for? First I thought it's for restriction by user_group, but there is an field "fe_group varchar(100) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL" for it. You can find the field also at the documentation [Preparing the database](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/1-prepare-the-database.html) , but I couldn't find a description for it, only for "fe_group".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`access_group` is the **be_user** group.

In TYPO3 you have an access-system similar to the unix-rights, where you can grnat access to pages (and records in the page).

There is a menu entry `System`->`Access` where you select a page and can set values for multiple levels recursive:

You can set `Owner` and `Group` and the granted rights which are assigned for
**Owner**, **Group**, **Everybody**

the rights are coded bitwise (other order than displayed):

1 (2^0) Show page: Show/Copy page and content.
2 (2^4) Edit content: Change/Add/Delete/Move content.
3 (2^1) Edit page: Change page eg. change pagetitle etc.
4 (2^2) Delete page: Delete/Move page and content.
5 (2^3) New pages: Create new pages under this page.

These values can be set with `TCEMAIN` in the page TSconfig, so all pages in a sub tree might get the same rights.

---

Example:

```
TCEMAIN.permissions {
    userid = 43
    groupid = 5
    user = 31
    group = 19
    everybody = 1
}
```

- Each page will get the user with the uid 43 as owner,
- the group will be the group with the uid 5,
- the owner has every right,
- the group can `show page`, `edit page`, `edit content` but can not `delete page` or `create new pages` below
- every one else can see the page

Alternatively you can set the rights by keywords:

```
TCEMAIN.permissions {
    userid = 43
    groupid = 5
    user = show, edit, delete, new, editcontent
    group = show, edit, editcontent
    everybody = show
}
```

---

comment from [Rudy Gnodde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10052668/rudy-gnodde), which I agree:

> This is only used for pages, not in custom tables for extensions. It's probably a mistake in this documentation. It should be fe_group I think (which is mentioned in this documentation, but not in the code example which contains access_group).

As TYPO3 manuals can be edited by everyone (there is a button `Edit me on GitHub` in the upper right corner), I have proposed a correction.

Comment: This is only used for pages, not in custom tables for extensions. It's probably a mistake in this documentation. It should be fe_group I think (which is mentioned in this documentation, but not in the code example which contains access_group).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Now it's clear, the documentation confused me and I also thought, that there is a mistake in the doc.