# TYPO3 how to properly configure access to a sub-branch of a workspace for a “limited user”

Tags: typo3

I want to create a user who can only access one sub-branch of a workspace.
This user cannot have access to the "LIVE" only to the workspace "DRAFT".

I tried to configure like this but it doesn't work:

- Create a workspace which can access all the page trees (db mount all
  tree)
- Creates a non-administrator user (for example an advanced editor)
  (with the respective backend group), who can access LIVE, and access
  all the page trees
- Create a non-administrator user (for example a limited editor) (with
  the respective backend group), who cannot access LIVE and access only
  a sub-branch page tree of the workspace (user db mount only a
  sub-branch).
- When the limited editor accesses his DRAFT workspace no page tree is
  displayed It appears the error “Page tree error Got unexpected
  response from the server. Please check logs for details."
- Reproduced on v8 v9 v10

Is it a bug or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

aside of workspace and database mounts a backend user needs the correct access rights for a page to do anything (including seeing) a page and its records.

a typical configuration might include a (sub)group so all editors belonging in that group have full access to a page and it's records.
If you want to avoid to set this rights for every new page anyone creates in that page tree make sure to set default values each new page gets when created:

more Information about the page TSconfig configuration can you get in [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60072878/6796354)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe I have configured everything correctly as described but the limited access editor does not work. If I give the publisher with limited access access to LIVE workspace it works, but that's not what I want. I am convinced it is a bug and I opened this report https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91918