# TYPO3 default group ownership

Tags: typo3

TYPO3 9.5.22

I have a TYPO3 based site with a number of department related subtrees, D1, D2, D3.

Users of department D1 are in backend group D1 and can work in the D1 Subtree via a DB mount.
Users of department D2 are in backend group D2 and can work in the D2 Subtree via a DB mount.

If a user U1D1 (Member of Group D1) creates a page in the D1 subtree, the page group owndership by the "admins" group.

This means that U2D1 can not edit pages of U1D1.

What do I have to do so pages created by U1D1 belong to group D1 instead of admins?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, a new page would get the main usergroup of a user (probably "admin" in your case).

You can override that by setting `TCEMAIN.permissions.groupid` in PageTS on the specific pagetree. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceMain.html#groupid

Don't hesitate to ask if you are unsure how to add it for a specific page tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did it for me!

Comment: One question remains: In our case the UxD1 users are all members of the group D1 which is a sub-Group of Editors, Editors is a top level group, so no connection to admins here.  So I guess,  D1 is the main group.

Comment: Solved, the site uses the bootstrap package. This package ships with PageTS which contains TCEMAIN.permissions.groupid = 1, and this is the id of the admins group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TYPO3 mechanism for setting default values for single fields of a record. in this case the records are `pages` and the default value in question is the group the page should belong to.

In case you have a complex system of user groups where multiple groups should be able to share access to the same pages it's helpful to introduce a helper group which is subgroup of the groups assigned to the users (typical for LDAP connections). in this way you have groups which own the pages, and multiple parent groups which include the owner groups.
As new pages are assigned the primary user group by default, you end up in a chaos which pages can be edited by which user. Especially if admins are involved too. Here it is necessary to assign clearly the owner group to any new pages.

more Info on the settings can be found in this SQ answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60072878/6796354

Comment: I agree with that, in our case is not that complex so it would be sufficient if all pages of a departement belong to either the department group or to the editors group which is the parent of all department groups. Users are separated by DB mounts. As stated above, the boostrap package seems to define admins as the default group – hence the behaviour I found. Will try to unset the default group and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the ownership and access rights on the access-page

[image]

Comment: This is true but if someone creates a new page, the group ownership of the newly created page is admins again. So a workaround is to tell everyone to assign the group ownership for each newly created page.